# Unable to Understand the Data Flow and Network Security Architecture

Tags: network, firewalls, sandbox

[image]Received the attached Network Connectivity Diagram with Network Security Components Integrated in the Network
Can some body explain how the Network Security is Applied for Threat and Intrusion Prevention for the attached Architecture Diagram

Comment: Welcome to the community. Your question lacks research effort..

Comment: Yeah . I agree with you , I am trying to understand the underlying Routing Concept to comprehend how the whole thing falls in place from Security Point of View . Have difficulty in transferring routing and Switching skills to the Architecture in Scope to comprehend the Data Flow